# Conditional XOR after Bit Test in Assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly, micro-optimization

I'm trying to make a bit of inline assembly that tests a bit at a given position of input b and if its a 1, it replaces b with a XOR b.

I have the error "operand size mismatch for bt".

When I compile with -O3, sometimes it looks like it works as intended. Its completely inconsistent though. Including sometimes computing correctly, and sometimes gives an error at compile time. (all with -O3).

Without -O3 it always gives an error at compile time.

The overall requirement for this is to be as fast as possible, and workable on most modern-day AMD64 processors.

```
unsigned long ConditionAdd(const unsigned long a, unsigned long b, const long pos) {

  // Intended behavior: Looks at bit in position pos in b: if that bit is a 1, then it replaces b with a xor b
  asm (
       "BT %[position], %[changeable] \n\t"
       "JNC to_here%=\n\t"
       "XOR %[unchangeable], %[changeable]\n\t"
       "to_here%=: "
       : [changeable] "=&r" (b)
       : [position] "mr" (pos), [unchangeable] "mr" (a), "[changeable]" (b)
       : "cc"
       );

  return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Without -O3 it always gives an error at compile time.

**You gave the compiler the option of picking memory for the [`bt`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bt) source operand**.  With optimization disabled, it does, so the result doesn't assemble.  `bt $imm, r/m` or `bt %reg, r/m` are the only forms encodeable.  (In Intel syntax like the manual, `bt r/m, imm` or `bt r/m, reg`).

Fortunately you didn't give `bt` the option of picking a memory destination for `bt` because it has crazy-CISC bitstring semantics that make it very slow in the reg, mem case, like 5 uops on Ryzen, 10 uops on SnB-family. (https://agner.org/optimize/ and/or https://uops.info).  You always want the compiler to load the operands into registers first.

You do only read `a` at most once, so it's reasonable to have it in memory.  OTOH, clang always picks `"m"` if you give it the choice of `"rm"` or `"mr"`.  This is a known missed-optimization bug, but if you care about clang it's generally a good idea *not* to give the compiler that option or it will spill a register ahead of an asm statement.

**Don't forget to allow immediates for `a` and `pos`.**  `xor` takes a 32-bit sign-extended immediate so you want an [`"e"` constraint](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html).  A 64-bit shift count can use a `"J"` constraint to restrict to immediates in 0..63, or you can let `bt` mask (aka modulo) the source operand for you even when it's an immediate.  But it's an assemble-time error for GAS to use a `bt` immediate  that doesn't fit in an `imm8`.  So you could use that to detect compile-time-constant `pos` that's much too large by just using an `i` constraint.  You could also imagine doing `.ifeq` asm macro stuff to do `%[pos] & 63` when `%[pos]` is numeric, otherwise just `%[pos]`.

BTW, you might as well use a simpler `[changeable] "+&r"(b)` read/write constraint instead of an output + matching constraint.  That's a more compact way of telling the compiler exactly the same thing.

But also, **you don't need an early-clobber**.  `bt` doesn't modify any integer registers, only EFLAGS, so no registers are written *before* the final read of an input-only operand.  If `a` and `b` are known to hold the same value, it's totally fine for the resulting asm to have `xor same,same` (a zeroing idiom) as the fall-through path.

```
unsigned long ConditionAdd(const unsigned long a, unsigned long b, const long pos) {

  // if (b & (1UL<<pos)) b ^= a;
  asm (
       "BT    %[position], %[changeable] \n\t"
       "JNC   to_here%=\n\t"
       "XOR   %[unchangeable], %[changeable]\n\t"
       "to_here%=: "
       : [changeable] "+r" (b)
       : [position] "ir" (pos), [unchangeable] "er" (a)
       : "cc"      // cc clobber is already implicit on x86, but doesn't hurt
       );

  return b;
}
```

> The overall requirement for this is to be as fast as possible, and workable on most modern-day AMD-64 processors.

Then you might not want a conditional branch at all.  Branchy code depends on the branch predicting well.  Modern branch predictors are very fancy, but if the branch isn't correlated with preceding branches or some other pattern you're screwed.  Profile with performance counters using `perf` for `branches` and `branch-misses`.

You *might* still want inline asm, though, because gcc is generally terrible at using `bt` to optimize stuff like `a & (1ULL << (pos&63))`, or `btc/s/r` for the `^=` / `|=`  / `&= ~` versions of it.  (clang is better sometimes, including here).

---

You might want a `bt` / `cmov` / `xor` to conditionally zero a tmp copy of `a` before XORing, because `0` is the additive / xor identity value: `b ^ 0 == b`.  Creating a zeroed reg for cmov is probably better than creating a 0 / -1 in a reg (e.g. with `bt` / `sbb same,same` / `and %tmp, %a` / `xor %a, %b`).  On Broadwell and later, and on AMD, `cmov` is only 1 uop.  And xor-zeroing can be off the critical path for latency.  Only AMD has dependency-breaking `sbb same,same`, and on Intel that's 2 uops if `cmov` is 2 uops.

Shifting the relevant bit to the top of a register to broadcast it with `sar reg, 63` is another option, but then you need `63-pos` in a register, I think.  That's still going to be worse than cmov for branchless.

But simply using `cmov` to select between `b` and `b^a` makes the most sense, especially if it's ok to destroy the register that you got `a` in.  (i.e. force the compiler to `mov` copy it if it wants to keep it around)

---

But did you try using pure C to let the compiler inline and optimize?  Especially if constant-propagation is possible.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm  Or if it's possible to auto-vectorize this with SIMD, with `a`, `b`, and `pos` coming from arrays?

(You can fall back to pure C when some inputs are compile-time constants using `__builtin_constant_p`.  Except in clang7.0 and earlier, where it's evaluated before inlining so it's always false for wrapper functions.)

IDK if it was intentional that you picked `unsigned long`, which is 32-bit in the Windows ABI, 64-bit on x86-64 System V.  And 32-bit in 32-bit mode.  Your asm is width-agnostic (16, 32, or 64-bit.  `bt` doesn't have an 8-bit operand-size version).  If you meant *definitely 64-bit* then use `uint64_t`.

```
// you had an editing mistake in your function name: it's Xor not Add.
unsigned long ConditionXor(const unsigned long a, unsigned long b, const long pos) {
    if ((b>>pos) & 1) {
        b ^= a;
    }
    return b;
}
```

compiles with clang9.0 [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'//+you+had+an+editing+mistake+in+your+function+name:+it!'s+Xor+not+Add.%0Aunsigned+long+ConditionXor(const+unsigned+long+a,+unsigned+long+b,+const+long+pos)+%7B%0A++++if+((b%3E%3Epos)+%26+1)+%7B%0A++++++++b+%5E%3D+a%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+b%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+gcc+and+clang+do+still+optimize+this+into+a+right-shift+and+test+the+low+bit%0Aunsigned+long+ConditionXor_naive(const+unsigned+long+a,+unsigned+long+b,+const+long+pos)+%7B%0A++++if+(b+%26+(1ULL%3C%3Cpos))+%7B%0A++++++++b+%5E%3D+a%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+b%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+attempt+to+hand-hold+the+compiler+into+mov+%2B+xor+in+parallel+with+BT,+before+CMOV%0A//+clang+deoptimizes+back+to+creating+a+zero.%0Aunsigned+long+ConditionXor_branchless_ILP(const+unsigned+long+a,+unsigned+long+b,+const+long+pos)+%7B%0A++++unsigned+long+tmp+%3D+b+%5E+a%3B%0A++++unsigned+long+retval+%3D+(b+%26+(1ULL%3C%3Cpos))+%3F+tmp+:+b%3B%0A++++return+retval%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3++-Wall+-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang900,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3++-Wall+-march%3Dskylake',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+9.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) to

```
# clang9.0 -O3  -Wall -march=skylake
ConditionXor(unsigned long, unsigned long, long)
        xorl    %eax, %eax          # rax=0
        btq     %rdx, %rsi
        cmovbq  %rdi, %rax          # rax =  CF ? a : 0
        xorq    %rsi, %rax          # rax = b ^ (a or 0)
        retq
```

But GCC it compiles basically as-written.  Although it will optimize `b & (1UL<<pos)` to `(b>>pos) & 1` for you.  BMI2 for `shlx` (single-uop variable-count shift instead of 3 uops on Intel for `shr %cl, %reg`) helps, so I used a `-march` that included it.  (Haswell or newer / Ryzen or newer)

```
# gcc9.2 -O3 -march=haswell
ConditionXor(unsigned long, unsigned long, long):
        xorq    %rsi, %rdi        # a^b
        movq    %rsi, %rax        # retval = b
        shrx    %rdx, %rsi, %rdx  # tmp = b>>pos
        andl    $1, %edx          # test  $1, %dl might be better
        cmovne  %rdi, %rax        # retval = (b>>pos)&1 ? a^b : b
        ret
```

The shrx+andl is equivalent to BT, except it sets ZF instead of CF.

If you can't enable BMI2 and have to use GCC, then inline asm for `bt` is probably a good idea.

**Otherwise use clang and get near-optimal branchless asm.**

I think clang could do better by pre-calculating `b^a` and using `cmov` to select between that an `b`, shortening the critical path by 1 cycle because that can happen in parallel with `bt`.

```
# hand-written probably-optimal branchless sequence.  Like GCC but using BT
        xor    %rsi, %rdi    # destroy tmp copy of a, in a "+&r"(tmp)
        bt     %rdx, %rsi
        mov    %rsi, %rax    # mov to an "=r"(output)
        cmovc  %rdi, %rax
    ret
```

Note the ILP: the first 3 instructions all depend purely on the inputs.  (`bt` doesn't write its destination reg).  They can all execute in the first cycle after RSI becomes ready.  Then all 3 inputs for CMOV are ready the next cycle (RDI, RAX, and CF).  So total latency = 2 cycles from any / each of the inputs, assuming single-uop CMOV.

You can easily turn that back into inline-asm using a tmp reg, and turning the hard-coded regs back into `%[name]` operands.  Make sure you tell the compiler that the `a` input is destroyed by making it read/write.  You can use separate `"r"(b)` input and `"=r"(b)` outputs, letting the compiler pick different registers if it wants.  You don't need a matching constraint.

---

#### Middle ground:  `asm` only for `bt`

Consider using inline asm only to wrap `bt` with a flag output operand, `"=@ccc"(cf_output)`, and leave the rest to the compiler.  This could let you get better asm from gcc without having to put the whole thing into asm.  This allows constprop and other possible optimizations for `a` and `a^b`, and gives GCC flexibility when layout out the function.  e.g. it doesn't have to do everything in one small block, it can interleave with other work.  (Not a big deal given OoO exec).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm still reading all of this as its a lot to sift through (especially for a newbie like me!). I just want to point out that naming it ConditionAdd was intentional as XOR in the field F_2 is equivalent to addition. Perhaps misleading, but as a mathematician its extremely relevant!

Comment: No variations using asm [flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#FlagOutputOperands)? You can use BT to get the bit, then C to do the xor.  clang seems to [like](https://godbolt.org/z/pRFmyx) this.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: oh, that's a good idea, and I hadn't realized clang finally added GCC6 flag-output support.  But too bad GCC uses `setc` / `test` on the result of `bt` because of the function call or something!  https://godbolt.org/z/zJ14kV.  It also still partly defeats constant propagation, and of course makes auto-vectorization impossible.  (AVX2 could do this with `vpsllvq` for `b<<(63-pos)` and use that high bit as a blend control.  Or other possibilities.  IDK if GCC/clang would actually do it for per-element-variable shift counts, though.)

Comment: @user11969451: ah ok, if the context of the function name is already 64 packed 1-bit values, then yes XOR = add-without-carry makes sense.  But that context was missing from the question so I wondered if you had an `add` version of this that you copied and modified to get an `xor` version or something.  Anyway, maybe see how David's idea of using GCC6 flag outputs to wrap just `bt` with inline asm works for the context where this inlines into in your real code.  Hopefully gcc avoids a braindead setc / test from setting flags before it's ready to use them in your case.

Comment: It looks like flags might be a (microscopic) bit better than your optimal.  As for constant propagation, if that's a real possibility, you could always wrap a `__builtin_constant_p` around the asm call and use your C code to benefit the other cases.  Something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/HMuCid) (how did we function before godbolt)?  Since [__builtin_constant_p](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fconstant_005fp) is a compile-time function, it won't affect (optimized) execution.  Auto-vectorization is beyond my scope.

Comment: "Except in clang" Wait, what now?  Looking at my link that uses __builtin_constant_p, main is just `mov eax, 2` when I use constants.  What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: ah, that's another clang development I hadn't noticed.  Apparently now clang/LLVM >= 8.0 is able to delay eval of `__builtin_constant_p` until after inlining.  See clang7.0 output for what I was talking about:  https://godbolt.org/z/0YoMph.  (I changed the asm block to avoid flag output, which older clang didn't support either).  clang 9 still hasn't fixed choosing `"m"` for an `"rm"` constraint, though.  I checked that just now (by making the constant branch false.)

Comment: It's not often I find things you missed, so today's a good day.  That said, gcc9.2 (what I assume OP is using) doesn't optimize using flags nearly as well as clang in this case.  That makes your answer better than mine (which is why I'm not posting one).

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I like the idea of only handling BT inside assembly, and it seems to work beautifully. I just have a question: what is the "Ir" for?

Comment: @user11969451: my answer covers that: small immediate or register.  Except it should be `Jr` for the 0..63 range, vs. Ir for the 0..31 range.  And also the fact that you might as well let it use a larger value because the wrapping is the same for immediate vs. register, e.g. any 0..255 is encodeable.